# Fix unexpected ALNUM for Igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to read a ncol file with Igraph in R.
I use: `read_graph("titles.txt", format="ncol")`.

When I use the first two lines of the file,
I got no errors, but when I do 100 lines it gives me:

```
Error in .Call("R_igraph_read_graph_ncol", file, as.character(predef),  : 
  At foreign.c:244 : Parse error in NCOL file, line 1 (syntax error, 
unexpected ALNUM, expecting NEWLINE), Parse error
```

The format looks something like this (label, tab, label, new line):

```
"Parent title name" "Child. Title"
"Parent-title"  "Also, a child-title"
"Parent title name" "Also, a child-title"
"Parent-title"  "Child. Title"
```

Is it because I use certain characters, or that I repeat names?
I want to make a tree layout, ncol and Igraph is new for me.

Comment: Are you sure that you can use quoted strings here? Maybe not.